# How can we check if a book is a sequel edition of an older one with different names?

Tags: citations

How do you check if  a book is a new edition of an older book, but they have different titles, without accessing the books? Are there websites which maintain such records?

For example, is [this book](http://lccn.loc.gov/2007012974)

```
Fundamentals of data structures in C / Ellis Horowitz, Sartaj Sahni, Susan Anderson-Freed.
Edition 2nd ed.
Published/Created   Summit, NJ : Silicon Press, 2008.
```

a newer edition to [this one](http://lccn.loc.gov/76015250)

```
Fundamentals of data structures / Ellis Horowitz, Sartaj Sahni.
Published/Created: Computer Science Press, c1976.
```

Does the second one have later editions?

Comment: Why would you _want_ to do this "without accessing the books"?  The easiest (perhaps the only) ways to find out are (1) read the preface of the more recent book, and (2) ask the author(s) directly.

Comment: (1) no access. (2) expect no reply.

Comment: According to the first author's web page (http://www.ellishorowitz.com/), _Fundamental Data Structures in C_ (1992) is one of several "Derived Versions" of _Fundamental Data Structures_ (1976).  It seems likely that _Fundamental Data Structures in C (2nd edition)_ (2008) is the second edition of the 1992 "derived version", but not (strictly speaking) a new "edition" of the original 1976 book.

Comment: @JeffE: Thanks. The background of my question is: I am interested in formally learning data structures. I felt the 1982 (not sure if it is the same as 1976) fits my taste. But I worry if it is outdated. I admit that I haven't had access to many books yet. If interested, could you leave some comments here or under my more relevant post http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/30627/is-horowitz-and-sahnis-data-structure-book-outdated ? I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's an easy way to track this. The [Library of Congress catalog](http://catalog.loc.gov), for instance, shows no trace that the second book was an earlier edition of the first. However, if the edition numbers are consecutive, there's usually no "intervening" edition.

Comment: thanks. is this the first edition for the first book: http://lccn.loc.gov/92002524 ? It is not the same as the second book.

Comment: No, it shouldn't be the same. [Here's the second book,](http://catalog.loc.gov/vwebv/holdingsInfo?searchId=3489&recCount=100&recPointer=10&bibId=3651760&searchType=7) representing the older edition. But what I meant is that there's no link in the newer book pointing back to the older one. You'd have to check for each book manually, or so it would seem.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no general answer to this, since sometimes a book is completely rewritten (including things like changing the computer language that is used in the books examples) and published as a second edition, while in other cases a book will be published by a new publisher under a different title with very few actual changes (typically after the authors have regained the copyright from the original publisher.)  The choice of whether or not to call the book a new edition is really up to the publisher.

As another example of the this, look at Don Norman's "The Psychology of Everyday Things" also known as "The Design of Everyday Things."  These are basically the same book with different titles.